# Execute part of graph in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Considering a simple custom model in tensorflow 2.0 like:

```
class Custom_Model(Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(Custom_Model, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')
    self.act1 = Activation('relu')
    self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')
    self.act2 = Activation('relu')
    self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(8, activation=None)

def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.act1(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.act2(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    logits = self.d1(x)
    value = self.d2(x)
    return logits, value
```

is there any way for the model to return only one of the outputs of the graph, e.g., value or logits? This used to be easily done in tensorflow 1.X using sessions

```
session.run(self.value, feed_dict={self.x: x})
```

But I couldn't figure it out how it is done in tensorflow 2.0!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Custom_Model(Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(Custom_Model, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')
    self.act1 = Activation('relu')
    self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')
    self.act2 = Activation('relu')
    self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(8, activation=None)

def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.act1(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.act2(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    logits = self.d1(x)
    value = self.d2(x)
    return logits, value

def returnValue(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.act1(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.act2(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    value = self.d2(x)
    return value
```